# Why go I get this error: "Could not find member 'append'"?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am new to Swift and am trying to do a GET request and parse the JSON response. After I parse the JSON and put it to a string array, it gives me the error:

> Could not find member 'append'

This is the full code:

```
var deviceListUUid = [String]();
func getDeviceList(uuid: String , name: String , pwd: String) {
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://" + SERVER_IP + ":" + PORT + "/account/user/" + uuid + "/associations")
    HttpGet_getDeviceList(url!, name: name, pwd: pwd)
}

func HttpGet_getDeviceList(url: NSURL,name: String , pwd: String){
    println("url = \(url)");
    var encode = name + ":" + pwd;

    var byte = [UInt8](encode.utf8)
    let nsdata : NSData = NSData(bytes: byte as [Byte], length: byte.count)
    let base64 : NSString = nsdata.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url);
    request.HTTPMethod="GET"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    let queue:NSOperationQueue = NSOperationQueue()

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: queue, completionHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!,error: NSError!) -> Void in
        let httpResponse = response as NSHTTPURLResponse
        if(httpResponse.statusCode == 200) {
            //analysis json
            let jsonObject : AnyObject! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil)
                self.AnalysisJSON(jsonObject)
        }else{
            self.setReplyStatus(CouchbaseEnum.ReplyStatus.LOGIN_ERROR)
        }
    })
}

func AnalysisJSON(json:AnyObject) {
    if var jsonArray = json["value"] as? NSArray{
        println("jsonArray.count = \(jsonArray.count)")
        for var i = 0 ; i < jsonArray.count; i++ {
            if var deviceID = jsonArray[i] as? NSDictionary {
                if var info = deviceID["info"] as? NSDictionary {
                    if var sessionUUid = info["sessionUuid"] as? NSString {
                        println("sessionUUid = \(sessionUUid)")
                        deviceListUUid[i].append(sessionUUid)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I call the function `getDeviceList`, it calls `HttpGet_getDeviceList` and get the JSON data and pass it to the function `AnalysisJSON`.

It is working fine so far. I want to put the JSON string data into the string array like this:

```
if var sessionUUid = info["sessionUuid"] as? NSString {
      deviceListUUid[i].append(sessionUUid)
}
```

But it gives me the error:

> Could not find member 'append'.

If I change from

```
deviceListUUid[i].append(sessionUUid)
```

to

```
deviceListUUid[i] = sessionUUid
```

it instead gives me this error:

> array index out of range

Did I missing something?

Comment: Another side note: as per convention use upper case first letter only for classes/structs, not for instances and funcs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing the element of the `deviceListUUid` array and try to append your value there. Since the element is of type `String`, it cannot find the `append` function, because `String` does provide an append but it append only a single character and *extends* the string you are accessing.

Instead, append your new string to the *array*:

```
deviceListUUid.append(sessionUUid)
```

**Note** IMO your semantics is not entirely correct. That is, to me it makes no sense to append `sessionUUid` to a list of device UUIDs. Instead, you probably want to create an array of device UUIDs (which you already have), which in turn contains an array of session UUIDs, or even better a dictionary mapping device UUIDs to session UUIDs (if that makes sense for your ultimate goal).

Comment: fwiw, `String` actually does provide an `append` method that takes `Character` or `UnicodeScalar` objects, but yeah, your answer is probably what he was looking for. ;)

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'll edit it, just looked it up because I was only 90% sure ;)